# Как динамически создавать элементы в Reactjs Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, reactjs

Подскажите пожалуйста(или дайте наводку на гайд, в котором это описывается), как организовать создание элемента на странице при выполнении пользователем какого-то действия. К примеру, у меня есть на странице selectfield, рядом с ним есть кнопка +. При нажатии на эту кнопку должны появляться такие же selectfield-ы чуть ниже. Я подумал было написать и повесить на кнопку onClick метод, который будет при нажатии вызывать метод-рендер selectfield-a,но мне кажется это неправильно, т.к. он по нажатии просто заново перерисует уже имеющийся филд. Как правильно организовать это взаимодействие?

Comment: При нажатии на + добавляешь элемент в какое-то твое хранилище, а это хранилище мапишь `list.map((row) => <MyElement data={row} />)`

Comment: а потом пробрасываю мапу в рендер?и ключи селектов,лежащих в мапе станут id этих селектов при рендеринге?

Comment: Можешь не пробрасывать а прямо писать в блоке рендера код который я написал. (в фигурных скобках конечно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведу пример из моего кода:

```
const {sources, actions, rows} = this.props;

const SourceList = rows.map(
    (row, key) => {
        const type = row.get('type');
        const props = {
            key,
            index: key
        };

        if (type === RowTypes.GROUP) {
            return <Group {...props}/>;
        } else if (type === RowTypes.VIRTUAL) {
            return <Virtual {...props} />
        }

        return <RowItem
            {...props}
        />
    }
);
```

У меня поля строятся по разным типам, а в `SourceList` в итоге будет построенная модель. В `render` нужно будет просто написать:

```
<div>{SourceList}</div>
```

Comment: мне нужно не совсем это. у меня есть класс селектфилда, в нем есть рендер и запрос по аяксу, по которому приходит список(из которого пользователь выбирает). также есть класс с формой,в котором рендерится форма, а в форму я просто подкидываю <UserSelectfield/>(этот селект имеет некий ref и source). также есть кнопка, которая должна ниже при нажатии генерить еще такие же селектфилды. то есть рендер у меня происходит в самом селекте и потом есть еще рандер формы.

Comment: какая разница, данные пришли, вы их записали (не знаю куда, может в состояние компонента) они отрендерелись, и сразу обновили все. У вас же DOM строется по данным, данные будут, интерфейс обновится

Comment: да,данные пришли, state селектфилда изменился.я не совсем понимаю, что именно вносить в мапу и где это осуществлять.в хендлере кнопки?

Comment: На кнопке должно быть событие, которое будет дописывать в массив ваших филдов элемент (пустой или какой то ещё вам нужный). Ну и он будет сразу же отрисован

Comment: та создание и инциализация массива где должна проводиться?

Comment: Я не знаю вашей архитектуры, у меня вообще все в редьюсерах обрабатывается, компоненты не знают логики, они только отрисовывают данные. А можно в конструкторе компонента объявить массив в `this.state = {myArray: []}`. А по клику на кнопку делать `this.setState()` в добавлением в `myArray` элемента. Но логика в компонентах зло, лучше все выносить, да и работать чисто с данными проще в редьюсерах

Comment: в redux мне бы пока не хотелось лезть. у меня на данный момент только в 1 месте такое добавление элементов. объявление в конструкторе компонента это в методе getInitialState?

Comment: Ну чем раньше вы разобьете логику с событиями от верстки, тем лучше, тем более в этом сложного мало что есть, а полезность зашкаливает. И это хороший опыт. Хотя странно что у вас интерфейс с одним событием, такое маловероятно) Он будет расти, а добавлять события в компоненты не удобно, их лучше объявлять в одном месте, а наследоваться они будут почти везде. Просто вызывать, просто манипулировать